# Import camera2 API samples as Java

Tags: java, android-studio, android-camera2

is it possible to import camera2 API sample from https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/main/Camera2Basic as java project in Android Studio or do I have to use Kotlin?

Comment: If you want to use some basic features, you can refer this for java, https://github.com/googlearchive/android-Camera2Basic but for latest and uo to date api, refer kotlin app.

Answer (score 0):

java and kotlin version (separate projects) :
https://github.com/nick570775/camera

original version :
https://github.com/googlearchive/android-Camera2Basic

update  project structure and settings   (java 11)

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33283041)